# Changing UI language in OpenOffice.org

Tags: openoffice, language

I'm trying to change the language in OpenOffice.org from German to English.

However when I go to:

> Optionen > Sprachen (Options > Languages)

the only possibility is German.

How do I add English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have the English language pack installed. Download it from [here](http://download.openoffice.org/other.html#tested-lp)

After installation you should see the option in the languages menu.

Comment: Worked, thanks. btw a restart is required for the language to be added.