# How do I get "Open Office" menu items to appear in English?

Tags: openoffice, language

I'm using my boyfriend's computer, so Open Office is in Japanese. Do I need to un-instal the Japanese version to be able to work in English? or is there a setting I can change?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this similar [SU question](https://superuser.com/questions/276340/changing-ui-language-in-openoffice-org). You shouldn't need to uninstall OpenOffice, but you'll need the English language pack. If it's not already there, you'll need to install it before you can can change the settings. Your boyfriend may need to help you find the appropriate (`Options > Languages`) menu setting in Japanese.